# BasicDynaBean returning nested empty rows from postgres query in java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jdbctemplate, apache-commons-beanutils

I am working on a spring boot app where I am working with postgres as a database and to fetch data I am using `JDBCTemplate` and storing it in `BasicDynaBean` type of object List.

Here's my code:

```
String query="SELECT * FROM students";
List<BasicDynaBean> result=JdbcTemplate.query(query, parameters, new RowToBasicDynaBeanMapper());

Map<String,Object> response=new HashMap<>();
response.put("result",result);
return result;
```

`RowToBasicDynaBeanMapper`

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BasicDynaBean;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

/*
 * Mapper for transforming ResultSet into a List of BasicDynaBeans using the RowSetDynaClass.
 */
final class RowToBasicDynaBeanMapper implements ResultSetExtractor<List<BasicDynaBean>> {
  @Override
  public List<BasicDynaBean> extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    ByteArrayToInputStreamRowSetDynaClass rowSetDynaClass =
        new ByteArrayToInputStreamRowSetDynaClass(resultSet);
    return (List<BasicDynaBean>) rowSetDynaClass.getRows();
  }
}
```

The above code triggers in Get request of a route and returns the result,But as a output I am getting this:

```
"result" : {
    "dynaClass" : {
      "rows" : [ {
        "dynaClass" : {
          "rows" : [ {
            "dynaClass" : {
              "rows" : [ {
                "dynaClass" ....nested long output
```

How can I get the correct output out of my query request?
Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: Is `RowToBasicDynaBeanMapper` your own class or part of any library? This looks like either an error in that mapper or an error in your JSON mapping, e.g. you get a back reference from the dyna class to the rows. I assume you're using Jackson so for the mapping problem you might want to look into mixins, which might help here in order to mark those back references to be ignored.

Comment: updating the code now

Comment: updated the RowtoBasicDynaBeanMapper @Thomas.Can you check now?